# A proposition concerning the position of Pascal points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

While answering a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373093/a-nice-cyclicity/4373897#4373897) I have found algebraically the following nice proposition related to [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem).

> *Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral and let $E$ and $F$ be arbitrary diametrically opposite points on its circumcircle. Further let $G=(AE)\cap(DF),H=(BE)\cap(CF),I=(AC)\cap(BD)$, and $O$ be the center of the circumcircle.*
>
> *Then: $$IG:IH=\tan\frac{\angle AOD}2:\tan\frac{\angle BOC}2.\tag1$$*

[image]

The proposition reveals that the ratio $IG:IH$ does not depend on the choice of the antipode points $E,F$, i.e. it is an "internal" property of cyclic quadrilateral.

My algebraic proof is very lengthy and cannot be reproduced here (essentially it is the same computation as reported in the linked answer).

Is this proposition known and can it be easily proved?

The collinearity of the points $G,I,H$ can be assumed as it follows from Pascal's theorem.

Comment: ...also equal to the slightly simpler expression $\tan \angle ACD / \tan \angle BAC$

Comment: I can myself bashing this with Menelaus starting from $\triangle HGF$ but it won't be much shorter than your coordinate bashing in that other post. If there is an elegant solution, it surely involves inversion/perspective/harmonic ratio all that stuff.

Comment: @JeanMarie I like more the central angle. :)

Comment: What I can think of is to use Menelaus's theorem...

Comment: A remark that could lead a different view on this issue: as I said upwards, your issue is equivalent to $\frac{IG}{IH}=\frac{\tan \angle ABD}{ \tan \angle BAC}$, but the right hand side, seen in triangle AIB, is equal to $\frac{KA}{KB}$ where $K$ is the orth. projection of $I$ onto $AB$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I present the Menelaus's theorem proof here... hope it is simpler. Let $EA\cap DB=Y$ and $EB\cap DF=X$, then, using the  Menelaus's theorem to triangle $EGH$ and line $YIB$, then use that theorem to triangle $XEG$ with line $DYB$, we have

$$\frac{GI}{HI}=\frac{GY}{YE}\frac{EB}{BH}=\frac{EB}{BH}\frac{GD}{DX}\frac{XB}{EB}=\frac{GD}{BH}\frac{XB}{DX}$$

Notice that $\frac{XB}{DX}=\frac{FB}{DE}$ (notice that if $EA\parallel DB$, this also holds.) Also notice that $\angle EDG=\angle EDF=90^\circ$, now we have:

$$\frac{GI}{HI}=\frac{GD}{BH}\frac{FB}{DE}=\frac{GD/DE}{BH/FB}=\frac{\tan \angle DEA}{\tan \angle CFB}=\frac{\tan \frac{\angle AOD}2}{\tan \frac{\angle BOC}2}$$

Comment: Could you explain in the final computation why $GD/DE=\tan \angle DEA$ (and $BH/FB=\tan \angle CFB$) ? Thanks !

Comment: @JeanMarie This is because $E,F$ are diametrically opposite points, so $\angle EDG=\angle EDF=90^\circ$. Therefore, $GD/DE=\tan \angle DEG=\tan\angle DEA$. The other one is analogous.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot follow. Applying the Menelaus theorem could you please specify what is the triangle and what is the line. I have a feeling that some letters are misplaced.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answering !

Comment: @user $\frac{GI}{HI}=\frac{GY}{YE}\frac{EB}{BH}$ is for triangle $EGH$ with line $YIB$, and $\frac{GY}{YE}=\frac{GD}{DX}\frac{XB}{EB}$ is triangle $XEG$ with line $DYB$. There are some typos, thank you for pointing out. The correct version is $EA\cap DB=Y$ and $EB\cap DA=X$.

Comment: I would be thankful if you introduce the explanations (including that one given in response to the @JeanMarie comment) into the body of your answer.

Comment: @user I did that.

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering how Menelaus was applied to triangle $XEG$ with line $DYB$, don't you need $D \in XG$ to be able to do that? Also, would you mind elaborating on how you got $\frac{XB}{DX} = \frac{FB}{DE}$, because from what I drew on geogebra this does not seem to be true. Could there be mislabelled points somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: @kaire Thank you very much for pointing out, there is a mislabel, $X=DF\cap EB$. I am really sorry for confusion, now I fixed that.